# Remove duplicate values from entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame as follows;

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,23,3,76,2,45,76],'B':[12,56,22,45,1,3,98,79,77,67]})
```

To remove duplicate values from the dataframe I have done this;

```
set(data['A'].unique()).union(set(data['B'].unique()))
```

which results in;

```
set([1, 2, 3, 12, 76, 77, 79, 67, 22, 23, 98, 45, 56])
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Is there a way of achieving this by using `drop_duplicates`?

Edit:

also, What if I had two more columns 'C' & 'D' but need to drop duplicates only from 'A' & 'B' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are intent on collapsing this

```
In [10]: np.unique(data.values.ravel())
Out[10]: array([ 1,  2,  3, 12, 22, 23, 45, 56, 67, 76, 77, 79, 98])
```

This will work as well

```
In [12]: data.unstack().drop_duplicates()
Out[12]: 
A  0     1
   1     2
   2     3
   4    23
   6    76
   8    45
B  0    12
   1    56
   2    22
   6    98
   7    79
   8    77
   9    67
dtype: int64
```

Comment: cool! What if I had two more columns 'C' & 'D' but need to drop duplicates only from 'A' & 'B' ?

Comment: ``drop_duplicates`` takes a ``cols`` argument (so you can specify a list)