# Python: Find unique value in 2 dataframe and avoid duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I Have two dataframe

```
df1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df2 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 9]
```

I want to get a new Df with only [4,5]
(I wrote number, but the real list are two lists of emails) 
Then I will turn save DataFrame into CSV file

How can i do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from entire dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561495/remove-duplicate-values-from-entire-dataframe)

Comment: Those are not dataframes but list.

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df2 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 9]
[x for x in df1 if x not in df2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like they are `list` , then we using `set`

```
set(df1)-set(df2)
Out[398]: {4, 5}
```

Comment: maybe go back to list: list(set(df1)-set(df2))

Comment: Worked, only problème is that I need DataFrame to export in CSV

Answer (score 0):

Diff pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 7, 9])
df3 = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
df3[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

Merging pandas dataframes:

`df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)`

Comment: With that method, i'll have df = [4, 5, 7, 9]

Comment: This merges 2 dataframes and removes duplicates. If you only want data from df1 then use @Daniele's answer.

Comment: added an example of finding the difference of 2 dataframes.